# how do I make a platform disappear when I bounce on it in unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine

My goal is to have a platform destroy if it is landed on.  Landing on the platform also bounces me up (it is an endless jumper).

The problem is the destroying of the layers isn't consistent. Sometimes the bounce and destroy work as intended, sometimes the platform won't get destroyed (if I bounce on it again it will destroy), other times the platform will destroy and the bounce won't initiate.  I am not sure how to make it work every time and why it isn't working properly.

This is the code I am using for the bounce:

```
public bool platformTouch;  //true or false if you are grounded
public Transform groundCheck; //Object which will check if we are grounded

public bool groundedTouch;
public LayerMask ground; //Decide which layers count as grounded.


float groundRadius = .2f;  //Radius around ground check object will check if grounded
public LayerMask platform; //Decide which layers count as grounded.

public Rigidbody2D Player;

void FixedUpdate()
{
        platformTouch = Physics2D.OverlapCircle(groundCheck.position, groundRadius, platform);

        groundedTouch = Physics2D.OverlapCircle(groundCheck.position, groundRadius, ground);
}
```

Here is the destroy code I am using.  If the player's velocity is less than 0 (falling) it should trigger the destroy.  There is also a delay in the destroy, so that the bounce triggers.

```
public Rigidbody2D Player;

void Update()
{
    Player = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player").GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
}

 void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collider)
{
    if (collider.gameObject.tag == "Destroyer")
    {
        if (Player.velocity.y <= 0)
        {
            StartCoroutine(DestroyPlatforms());
        }
    }
}

IEnumerator DestroyPlatforms()
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(.1f); //waits .1 seconds
    Destroy(gameObject); //this will work after .1 seconds.
    //play sound

}
```

Comment: I strongly suggest you moving `Player = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player").GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();` to `void Start()`. Reason behind this is simple: FingGameObjectWithTag/GameObject.Find and GetComponent are very expensive functions. Right now you're doing it every frame, better solution is to cache it once at start and then reuse.
Regarding to question: Have you tried `OnCollisionEnter2D` instead of `OnTriggerEnter2D`?

Comment: Your player velocity is sometimes maybe not reaching zero, depending of how it's moved and smoothed. Try with 0.1f or 0.5f !

Comment: I moved the Rigibidbody code, thank you.  The OnCollisionEnter didn't work.  It seems to not recognize they were colliding.  I think it may have to do with the way he trigger is coded and how it doesn't use a Rigidbody as the triggering mechanism.

Comment: Even changing the velocity doesn't change the problem.  At the apex of the jump the platform still does the wierd behavior.

Comment: Have you tried completely removing the if statement that tests the player's velocity? Also, why is that test necessary? Just from seeing this bit of code and trying to picture your game, it seems like the velocity or player's movement (other than contact) doesn't play a role in when the platforms are destroyed.

Comment: It is an endless jumper and you can jump through the platforms.  So they were disappearing on the way up.

Comment: Why not just launch the player when it enters the trigger, and then launch it?

Answer (score 2):

I recommend that you increase your collider on the platform and use OnTriggerExit with Destroy(this,0.1) , again I can be wrong. But mb it will help

Comment: @TimCooley any luck getting this to work? You might want to try Destroy(this.gameObject, 0.1f) as well.

Answer (score 1):

Physics engines are not deterministic, and it's usually not a good practice to have 2 objects checking for the same collision (one object could trigger and not the other in the same frame) I think that's the problem here.

The collision should only be handled by the platform and call a bounce method on the player in the OnTriggerEnter2D right before calling the      StartCoroutine(DestroyPlatforms());